# OperationalError at /no such table: django_session error on public server, site works fine on local server

Tags: python, django, webserver

I am trying to send data taken from a form to another views page to process it. I am using sessions to send that data. It works fine on a local host, the data is sent and received successfully, however, on a public server it crashes. I found a couple of posts regarding the same problem but their issue is mostly related to database integration which is not the case here. 
This is the code that is causing the error its inside views.py:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from django.templatetags.static import static
 from plots.forms import plotform
 from django.http import JsonResponse 
 #from rest_framework.views import APIView
 #from rest_framework.response import Response
 import numpy as np 
 import csv
 import math
 import json

def plots2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = plotform(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    frequency_min = form.cleaned_data['frequency_min']
                    frequency_max = form.cleaned_data['frequency_max']
                    distance  = form.cleaned_data['distance']
                    humidity  = form.cleaned_data['humidity']
                    temp  = form.cleaned_data['temp']
                    request.session['frequency_min'] = frequency_min 
                    request.session['frequency_max'] = frequency_max 
                    request.session['distance'] = distance 
                    request.session['humidity'] = humidity 
                    request.session['temp'] = temp
                    return redirect('plots/')

    form = plotform() #includes the form inside plots.html
    #render(request, 'plots/plots2.html', {'form':form})
    #return redirect(request.POST.get('next','plots/'))
    #return redirect('plots/plots')
    return render(request, 'plots/plots2.html', {'form':form})


 def plots(request):

    frequency_min_input = request.session['frequency_min']
    frequency_max_input = request.session['frequency_max']
    distance_input      = request.session['distance']
    humidity_input      = request.session['humidity']
    temperature_input   = request.session['temp']
```

This is the error I get on the browser:

```
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://142.93.51.83/
 Django Version:    1.8.7
 Exception Type:    OperationalError
 Exception Value:   
 no such table: django_session
 Exception Location:    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist- 
 packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 318
 Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
 Python Version:    2.7.12
 Python Path:   
 ['/home/django/django_project',
  '/home/django/django_project',
  '/usr/bin',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
  '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
  Server time:  Fri, 10 Aug 2018 00:49:07 +0000
```

Comment: Did you set django_sessions?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you set session middleware properly.

First, Please check if you set sessionmiddleware properly.
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES should have

> 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'

And add it to django apps. INSTALLED_APPS should have

> 'django.contrib.sessions'

And generate migration / migrate app again.

> python manage.py makemigrations
>
> python manage.py migrate

Comment: session middleware was already set up. But I ran both makemigrations and migrate commands and now I get another error which is OperationalError at /
attempt to write a readonly database.

Comment: Everything works fine on my local server but on the public server it crashes with the error above. The only difference I can spot is that my local server is using python 3 and the public server is using python 2.7, do you think this is whats causing the error?

Comment: also in the project directory there is the file db.sqlite3, and in settings  this is the setup DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}                                                                                                                                      I dont think I did any other changes to setup to the database

Comment: Please check if your app has proper permission to write to database. If you are using sqlite db in the cloud server, then check if your app has proper permission to create db file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with :

sudo chmod 777 project directory
sudo chmod 777 database file

Answer (score 0):

run this

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have even deleted your DB file by mistake, or it could have moved elsewhere in the directory structure. It is always advisable to keep a copy of the database file.
Frankly, this happened to me once. I was integrating someone else's code  after committing mine, yet I replaced the DB file of her,  because, it was of the same name (db.sqlite3), but there was no content in it. And I got the same error.
Thankfully, I had kept a copy and the world (Website) was fine again! Got saved.